# how to select the value of Jquery UI Combobox using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

How to select the value of JQuery UI ComboBox using javascript. Here is the HTML.

```
<select id="combobox" class="custom-combobox" name="n">
                        <option>Select Action</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                    </select>
```

following is the JQuery UI Combobox .

```
(function( $ ) {
    $.widget( "custom.combobox", {
        _create: function() {
            this.wrapper = $( "<span>" )
                .addClass( "custom-combobox" )
                .insertAfter( this.element );

            this.element.hide();
            this._createAutocomplete();
            this._createShowAllButton();
        },
        _createAutocomplete: function() {
            var selected = this.element.children( ":selected" ),
                value = selected.val() ? selected.text() : "";

            this.input = $( "<input>" )
                .appendTo( this.wrapper )
                .val( value )
                .attr( "title", "" )
                .addClass( "custom-combobox-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-left" )
                .autocomplete({
                    delay: 0,
                    minLength: 0,
                    source: $.proxy( this, "_source" ),
                    select: function( event, ui){
                        messagetext_log( ui.item ?
                            ui.item.value:
                            "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value );
                    }

                })
                .tooltip({
                    tooltipClass: "ui-state-highlight"
                });

            this._on( this.input, {
                autocompleteselect: function( event, ui ) {
                    ui.item.option.selected = true;
                    this._trigger( "select", event, {
                        item: ui.item.option
                    });
                },

                autocompletechange: "_removeIfInvalid"
            });
        },
        _createShowAllButton: function() {
            var input = this.input,
                wasOpen = false;

            $( "<a>" )
                .attr( "tabIndex", -1 )
                .attr( "title", "Show All Items" )
                .tooltip()
                .appendTo( this.wrapper )
                .button({
                    icons: {
                        primary: "ui-icon-triangle-1-s"
                    },
                    text: false
                })
                .removeClass( "ui-corner-all" )
                .addClass( "custom-combobox-toggle ui-corner-right" )
                .mousedown(function() {
                    wasOpen = input.autocomplete( "widget" ).is( ":visible" );
                })
                .click(function() {
                    input.focus();

                    // Close if already visible
                    if ( wasOpen ) {
                        return;
                    }

                    // Pass empty string as value to search for, displaying all results
                    input.autocomplete( "search", "" );
                });
        },
        _source: function( request, response ) {
            var matcher = new RegExp( $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i" );
            response( this.element.children( "option" ).map(function() {
                var text = $( this ).text();
                if ( this.value && ( !request.term || matcher.test(text) ) )
                    return {
                        label: text,
                        value: text,
                        option: this
                    };
            }) );
        },
        _removeIfInvalid: function( event, ui ) {

            // Selected an item, nothing to do
            if ( ui.item ) {
                return;
            }

            // Search for a match (case-insensitive)
            var value = this.input.val(),
                valueLowerCase = value.toLowerCase(),
                valid = false;
            this.element.children( "option" ).each(function() {
                if ( $( this ).text().toLowerCase() === valueLowerCase ) {
                    this.selected = valid = true;
                    return false;
                }
            });

            // Found a match, nothing to do
            if ( valid ) {
                return;
            }

            // Remove invalid value
            this.input
                .val( "" )
                .attr( "title", value + " didn't match any item" )
                .tooltip( "open" );
            this.element.val( "" );
            this._delay(function() {
                this.input.tooltip( "close" ).attr( "title", "" );
            }, 2500 );
            this.input.data( "ui-autocomplete" ).term = "";
        },
        _destroy: function() {
            this.wrapper.remove();
            this.element.css('visibility','visible');
        }
    });
    $( "#messagetext" ).val(function(){return this.value + message + ', '}).prependTo( "#messagetext" );
})( jQuery );
```

Here Is what I am trying to do using javascript. But can get the option value to be selected.

```
reInsertComboBoxMessage=document.getElementById("combobox");

reInsertComboBoxMessage.options[1].selected=true;
```

AND

```
reInsertComboBoxMessage=document.getElementById("combobox");

   reInsertComboBoxMessage.value="1";
```

OR

```
 $("#combobox").val('1');
```

On the fiddle it works fine
http://jsfiddle.net/pratik24/bwNUG/
So should there be a problem with the UI import.

I think this is what is causing the problem. But dont know what to do now.I can remove it. Because I need the Jquery UI styling on the combobox. If I remove this function every thing works fine.

```
$(function (){

 $( "#combobox" ).combobox();
*$( "#toggle" ).click(function() {
        $( "#combobox" ).toggle();
    });
});
```

Fiddle---http://jsfiddle.net/pratik24/bwNUG/2/

Comment: Try jQuery's method `.is()`. It works like `if($(".elem").is("checked"))`

http://api.jquery.com/is/

Comment: what browser are you using? and do you have any javascript errors on the page? Do you think it would be possible to recreate the problem on fiddle? it's rather difficult to debug a problem you can't reproduce :P

Comment: I think I did recreate the problem in fiddle. here
http://jsfiddle.net/pratik24/bwNUG/2/

Comment: @user2415379 is this the error you get in your app as well? Just to make sure folks aren't wasting time... ReferenceError: messagetext_log is not defined
messagetext_log( ui.item ?

Comment: That was defined. But the error is solved. The error was in the json value that was being fetched back. 

. Thanks .